# FFTW in Qt Creator

Tags: windows, qt, fftw

I try to make a program that computes FFTW from IQ data. 
Windows 10 64 bits. Qt Creator 4.8.2 Based on Qt 5.12.2 (MSVC 2015, 32 bit)
The program crashed when I use

```
fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFT_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

I download fftw-3.3.5-dll64 and dll32, with both the same result.

.pro

```
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/fftw-3.3.5-dll32
QMAKE_LIBDIR += $$PWD/fftw-3.3.5-dll32
LIBS += $$PWD/fftw-3.3.5-dll32/ -llibfftw3-3
LIBS += $$PWD/fftw-3.3.5-dll32/ -llibfftw3f-3
LIBS += $$PWD/fftw-3.3.5-dll32/ -llibfftw3l-3
```

.cpp

```
include "fftw3.h"

int main()
{
    int N;
    fftw_complex *in, *out;
    fftw_plan myPlan;

    in = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)* N);
    out = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)* N);


    fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFT_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);  //this line crashed the program.

    fftw_execute(myPlan);

    fftw_destroy_plan(myPlan);
    fftw_free(in);
    fftw_free(out);
}
```

I hope some one can help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: You never initialize `N`.

Comment: Yes. In this case this is the basic example. But at the full proyect I make N initialize and crashed

Comment: Please edit your question to show the real code (preferably a [mcve]) that can be used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This has neither to do with Windows nor with QtCreator. You have to write the program correctly.

`fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);  //this line crashed the program.`

This is not the line that crashes. This line is just fine. The next will crash totally expectedly, because you never assigned  `myPlan`.

`myPlan = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N, in, out, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);`

will correct your problem. That is provided that you set `N` to something reasonable. I'm sure that you also should set `in` at least. Ecept of course you want to Fourier transform whatever happens to be at `in` in your RAM. Which is a cool thing. :)